# Как при наведении курсора мыши на кнопку менять её картинку в PyQt5?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qicon

Мне нужно чтобы при наведении на кнопку "Начать" менялась картинка на другую (прикреплю ниже).

Картинки:

[image: Это первая картинка]

Вторая:

[image: Вторая картинка, надо что бы она становилась при наведении курсора на кнопку]

Мой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.Qt import *

russia_language = True

try:
    from PyQt5.QtWinExtras import QtWin
    myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version'
    QtWin.setCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
except ImportError:
    pass


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        filename = 'music.mp3'
        fullpath = QtCore.QDir.current().absoluteFilePath(filename)
        url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(fullpath)
        content = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(url)
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setMedia(content)
        self.player.setVolume(50)
        self.player.play()

        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.slider.setRange(0, 100)
        self.slider.setValue(50)
        self.slider.setGeometry(800, 620, 300, 70)
        self.slider.hide()
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.player.setVolume)

        def Button(btn_name, text, color1, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color, mains):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            btn_name.setText(text)
            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "background-color: " + color1 + "; color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont('MS Serif', 14))
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)

        def Button_2(btn_name, text, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color, size):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            btn_name.setText(text)
            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Pusia-Bold.otf', size))
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            # btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)

        def Button_3(btn_name, text, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color, mains):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            if text == "Настройки громкости":
                btn_name.setCheckable(True)
                btn_name.setText(f'{text}: ({self.slider.value()})')
            else:
                btn_name.setText(text)
            # +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont('MS Serif', 14))
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)

        def Image(lbl_name, move_1, move_2, resize_1, resize_2):
            lbl_name.setPixmap(self.pix)
            lbl_name.move(move_1, move_2)
            lbl_name.resize(resize_1, resize_2)

        self.lbl2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)

        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("image.jpg")
        Image(self.lbl2, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)

        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("System_image/textbox.png")
        Image(self.lbl1, 0, 800, 1920, 300)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_2(self.btn1, "Вы появились в неизвестном вам месте,\nгде было невероятно красиво", 10, 1400, 200, 260, 830, "White", 30)
        self.inv = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/inventory_btn.png")
        Image(self.inv, -30, 600, 156, 96)
        self.btn31 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn31, "", 0, 100, 100, 0, 600, "White", self.inventory)
        self.inv_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/inventory.png")
        Image(self.inv_open, 70, 40, 1770, 996)
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn4, "", 5, 100, 100, 1650, 110, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn4.close()
        self.lbl20 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("System_image/Selection_menu.png")
        Image(self.lbl20, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.mg_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/Magazine.png")
        Image(self.mg_open, -30, 480, 156, 96)
        self.btn5 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn5, "", 0, 100, 100, 0, 480, "White", self.event_log)
        self.btn6 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn6, "", 0, 460, 800, 160, 170, "White", self.notes)
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn7, "", 0, 460, 800, 700, 170, "White", self.easter)
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn8, "", 0, 460, 800, 1260, 170, "White", self.tasks)
        self.btn8.close()
        self.notes_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Notes.png")
        Image(self.notes_open, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn9, "", 5, 80, 80, 1730, 50, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn9.close()
        self.easter_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Easter.png")
        Image(self.easter_open, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn10, "", 5, 80, 80, 1730, 50, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn10.close()

        self.tasks_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Tasks.png")
        Image(self.tasks_open, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn11 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn11, "", 5, 80, 80, 1730, 50, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn11.close()

        self.lbl2.close()
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.btn6.close()

        self.btn_start = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn_start, "Начать", 20, 300, 100, 800, 400, "Black", self.start)
        # !!!
        self.btn_select = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn_select, "Настройки громкости", 20, 500, 100, 710, 520, "Black", self.volume_custom)

    def inventory(self):
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.inv_open.show()
        self.btn4.show()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.btn6.close()

    def inventory_close(self):
        self.btn1.show()
        self.lbl1.show()
        self.inv.show()
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4.close()
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9.close()
        self.mg_open.show()
        self.btn5.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10.close()
        self.btn11.close()
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn31.show()

    def animations(self):
        animation = QPropertyAnimation(self)
        animation.setTargetObject(self.btn_name)
        animation.setPropertyName(b'pos')
        animation.setStartValue(QPoint(250, -200))
        animation.setEndValue(QPoint(250, 0))
        animation.setDuration(500)
        animation.start()

    def event_log(self):
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.lbl20.show()
        self.btn6.show()
        self.btn7.show()
        self.btn8.show()

    def notes(self):
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.notes_open.show()
        self.btn9.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()

    def easter(self):
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.easter_open.show()
        self.btn10.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()

    def tasks(self):
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.tasks_open.show()
        self.btn11.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()

    # !!!
    def start(self):
        self.btn1.show()
        self.lbl1.show()
        self.inv.show()
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4.close()
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9.close()
        self.mg_open.show()
        self.btn5.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10.close()
        self.btn11.close()
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn31.show()
        self.lbl2.show()
        self.slider.close()
        self.btn_select.close()
        self.btn_start.close()

    # !!!
    # +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def volume_custom(self):
        # тут действие, но я поставил print что бы не выдавал ошибку
        sender = self.sender()
        print(f'def volume_custom(): {sender.text()} - {sender.isChecked()}')

        if sender.isChecked():
            self.slider.show()
        else:
            self.slider.close()

        sender.setText(f'Настройки громкости: ({self.slider.value()})')


# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('System_image/icon.png'))
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.setWindowTitle('Story Telling')
    ex.setWindowIcon(QIcon('System_image/icon.png'))
    ex.showFullScreen()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте подкласс

```
class PushButton(QPushButton):
    ...
```

и переопределите в нем методы

- **enterEvent**(self, event)
- **leaveEvent**(self, event)

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class PushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.icon_1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        self.icon_1.addPixmap(
# !!! установите свои      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  изображения
            QtGui.QPixmap("img/Fo2BxBK.gif"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 160))
        self.setIcon(self.icon_1)
        
        self.icon_2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        self.icon_2.addPixmap(
# !!! установите свои     vvvvvvvvvvvvv  изображения
            QtGui.QPixmap("loading.gif"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 160))

        self.setFixedSize(180, 160)        
        
    def enterEvent(self, event):  
        self.setIcon(self.icon_2)
        self.window().label.setPixmap(self.window().pix_2)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setIcon(self.icon_1)
        self.window().label.setPixmap(self.window().pix)
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.сentralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.сentralWidget)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
# !!! установите свои             vvvvvv  изображения
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(200, 200)
# !!! установите свои               vvvvvvvvvvv  изображения
        self.pix_2 = QtGui.QPixmap("loading.gif").scaled(400, 300)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pix)

        self.btn_start = PushButton(self)
        self.btn_start.clicked.connect(lambda: print('Hello btn_start.clicked'))
        
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.сentralWidget) 
        main_layout.addWidget(self.label, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.btn_start, alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(1000, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]